# MVC3 AjaxHelper choosing selected DDL values without custom javascript

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm creating a site where I don't want anything to be done via custom javascript/jquery code at all, and I'm not sure it's going to be possible so need some advice.

The things that I want to be able to do are:

1. Load a JQuery (or Jquery style) dialog box containing a partial view.
2. Have a button that will select the "SelectedValue" from a dropdown list and render a partial view. (e.g. select a user from a dropdown and then click a button to add them to a list)
3. Append a partial view to an existing div.

I'm sure that all the above can be done using custom javascript, but what I want to is to use the standard Ajax and Html helpers that come with MVC3.

Main reason is that I've been struggling to get to grips with jQuery, but I also thought it would be nice to see if it can all be done without having to add a new script to the site.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated (even if it's just pointing me to articles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can use the Ajax.BeginForm method to do this.

There are issues with the fact that it has been in a separate form as I can't nest the forms though.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Ajax and Html helpers that come with MVC3 are for handling server-side stuff. Even the @Html.ValidationMessageFor helper usually uses their unobtrusive validation lib for jQuery validate.

Keep trying at jQuery, you'll get it. There is a reason it is so popular!

**Update**

I believe you can do #3 using @Ajax.ActionLink, but don't think you can do 1 or 2 out of the box with the Ajax html helper.

Comment: thanks for the encouragement! I'm not the greatest developer, but like to dable, so doing it through the ajax helper is nice.  I'll see if anyone else comes up with a better answer in the next day or so and if not I'll make this as the answer.

Comment: I've been playing around with Ajax.BeginForm and it seems that I can tackle point 2 with that... thoughts?